Azure AI Fine-Tuned Model Hosting: Cold Start Time When Starting and Stopping on Request?
I'm considering using Azure AI services to host a fine-tuned model and noticed that there's an hourly cost associated with hosting. To manage expenses, I'm wondering if it's possible to start the model only when there's a request and then stop it afterward to avoid ongoing costs.
Specifically, I’d like to know:

Is it possible to stop the model after training to avoid continuous
hosting costs, or would I need to remove the model entirely?
If stopping the model is possible, how long does it typically take to
start it again (i.e., what is the cold start time)?
Are there any best practices or strategies for managing hosting costs
effectively when using Azure AI for fine-tuned models?

I haven't implemented this yet, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
